# How to upgrade to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1

Tags: 8.1, windows-10-mobile, update, lumia-540

I'm have a Windows Phone (`Microsoft Lumia 540`) currently running `Windows Phone 8.1`. I want to upgrade the mobile's OS to `Windows 10 Mobile`.

I tried using Settings->Update Phone, but it displayed `Downloading 0%` for long and long time. My Wifi is working just fine as other applications are running smoothly using same network.

What is the issue with OS upgrading?

Answer (score 1):

A probable cause is your phone has insufficient memory. The Windows 10 Mobile update requires at least 1.4Gb of free `onboard` storage available. In order to free up space, you need the **[Upgrade Advisor app](http://aka.ms/W10MUpgradeAdvisor)**. Download it from the store, and it will assist you with the Windows 10 Mobile upgrade, as well as helping you free up some space by deleting temporary files and suggesting what needs to be done so as to proceed with your upgrade process.

Also, you can manually move stuff from your phone storage into a Micro SD Card, if you have one in your phone. Download and use the **[Microsoft Files](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Files/9WZDNCRFJ3PL)** app to do that using your phone.. Alternatively, you can copy it to your computer or upload it to OneDrive and then restore it later onto your phone.

However, if storage space is not the issue, I advise you do a **soft reset** before retrying to upgrade:

Whilst your phone is on:

> Press and hold the <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> and <kbd>Power</kbd> buttons at the same time until you feel a vibration (about 10–15 seconds). Ignore the "slide down to power off" screen
>  When the phone vibrates to signify powering up, release the buttons immediately and let the phone restart.

Soft resetting a phone usually resolve most phone and application problems.

After doing so, download the [Upgrade Advisor](http://aka.ms/W10MUpgradeAdvisor) application from the store, and continue to run it. It will assist you with the software upgrade.

Comment: I used Upgrade Advisor app from store, it allowed me to free up some space, when its done, then after pressing `Next`, it comes `Downloading 0%` and it continues...

Comment: Try the next solution I suggested up there: Soft Resetting

Comment: What about photos and other data in phone ?

Comment: Soft resets DO NOT delete any data.. Completely safe to undertake.. The only thing that soft resets might affect are the date and time, whichc you can correct upon the phone's restart

Comment: Note that soft reset also deletes all your installed apps. It basically returns the  phone to factory settings.

Comment: It is hard reset @Jason

Comment: @User5 sorry i guess i was wrong.

Comment: @JasonStack You're wrong. Soft resets do not delete installed applications...

Comment: I actually expected hard reset to be done with a hammer or something! lol!

Comment: hahaha, its actually that simle. Just that people always assume its complicated stuff