# Can't download windows 10

Tags: windows-10-mobile

My windows 10 refuses to download on my Lumia 535!It start and stops at 0% and fails,I've tried several times,but it isn't working.Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/13467/106